# Version numbers

Tags: discussion

I find, that quite often OPs have to be asked for

- OS
- OS version
- terminal
- terminal version
- vi/vi clone used
- version
- even more so, if sshing into another host is involved.

Would it be possible to ask OPs in the ask a question mask to provide this information or provide tags for the various versions? It would be nice for me to exclude windows for example.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions

Comment: @Rich No, I haven't

Comment: Certainly not version tags. -.-" Those are rarely useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit conflicted about this. It's often very useful to have that information, and it's not always obvious to the OP whether that information is relevant. But on the other hand, very often it's *not* relevant, and I find it irritating to have it cluttering up the question when that is the case.

Perhaps the best scenario would be to always recommend users include it (as you suggest) but for it to be removed if it subsequently turns out it's not pertinent.

Comment: How can this be set into motion

Comment: @mike There is no feature to include a "question template" or anything of the sort at the moment. The best we can do is edit some help page somewhere, but who is reading those? Probably very few people. if I ask very nice I can *maybe* get a SE employee to change the sidebar when asking a question, but I think that's also not very often read. Actually, even issue templates on e.g. GitHub are frequently just ignored :-(